# Drupal change multi select to checkboxes on views exposed form not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I needed to have all taxonomy vocabularies available to filter on, without adding all of the taxonomies one at a time.

I did this using the **Content: Has taxonomy terms (Multiple)** Filter - which renders out as a multiple select list.

I needed to change the select list to checkboxes, but BEF didnt allow me to do that for this type of field, so i did the following...

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {

      $options = $form['filter']['#options'];
      unset($form['filter']);

      foreach($options as $vocab => $terms) {

        foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
            $newkey = $options[$vocab][$key]->option;
            $termoptions[$vocab][key($newkey)] = $newkey[key($newkey)];
        }
        $form[$vocab] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkboxes',
          '#options' => $termoptions[$vocab],
          '#title' => $vocab,
          '#multiple' => TRUE,

        );

      }

  }

}
```

The exposed form looks good, but it doesnt work.

I think its because the name of the query is wrong. As i have split up the heirarchy into separate fields, the url used to look like

> mysite.com/category?filter[]=123

Now it looks like...

> mysite.com/category?Brand[123]=123

So theres how far ive got, any ideas how i can make this exposed form work?

I had a poke around at changing the submit handler views_exposed_form_submit but i dont know what i would need to change.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters this module do this for you

Comment: Hi, I tried BEF like you suggested, but it didnt provide an option to turn that filter into checkboxes

Comment: how to know  "it didnt provide an option to turn that filter into checkboxes" where you find options for this

Comment: Ive posted the same question here with screenshots... https://www.drupal.org/node/2882381

Answer (score 0):

i am updating my ans once again for more clear view
step one expose filter
[image]

settings for this

[image]
click on settings text then 
[image]
then gor for bef 
[image]
and the result is 
[image]
hope it make sense now

Comment: Yeah thats not there, no option for checklist, just "Default select list"

Comment: do it by step by step thats why i attach screen shot it should be there

Comment: i see your screen shot that is default settings for exposed form set it exposed as Better Exposed Filters first

Comment: Thanks, but thats the wrong filter, can you try it with "Content: Has taxonomy terms (Multiple)" and see if you can get it to work?

Comment: what multiple ?  Allow multiple selections is enabled and working

Comment: No, multiple vocbularies. Your are using the filter Has Taxonomy Term, I am using the filter Has Taxonomy TermS - with an 'S'. It is a filter that allows you to filter on multiple taxonomy vocabularies and their terms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145531/discussion-between-code-rider-and-collins).